# Is it possible to view encrypted documents in XPages?

Tags: xpages

I know that working with encrypted documents in XPages was not possible a couple of years ago. But in the meantime we got the ID vault and iNotes is able to work with encrypted documents, isn't it?

My research didn't brought a clear answer if the XPages engine is able to work with ID vault in order to get decryption keys from a user ID and view an encrypted document. Is this possible now? If so, how?

Comment: FYI: Document encryption/decryption is coming in 9.0.1 FP8: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/8d1c0550e6242b69852570c900549a74/26aa7417bb60f7df852580b40072af2d?OpenDocument

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Document encryption is now built into XPages and set for delivery in Feature Pack 8. The implementation supports both secret key and public/private key encryption. The Domino document data source has been extended to automatically decrypt/encrypt documents via a new 'encryptionKeysProvider' property ... or you can code up custom behavior via SSJS or Java in the XPages app. There are also new XPages @Functions and a Domino Designer wizard to simplify the process. It will be part of my Dev 1671 presentation at Connect 2017 (A Deep Dive into the Feature Pack Pipeline for Domino App Dev). I will provide enablement materials around the same time.

Comment: It's mentioned in the doc:
IBM Notes/Domino 9.0.1 Feature Pack 8 Preliminary Release Notice http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/8d1c0550e6242b69852570c900549a74/26aa7417bb60f7df852580b40072af2d?OpenDocument

Comment: That is good news. Can they keys be stored outside of the names.nsf?

Comment: I guess the secret keys can be stored anywhere (profile doc, other db, in the end-user's head, etc). They are entered into the XPage at runtime using a Secret Key Picker which can lookup the IDVault or any arbitrary source (or they can be manually typed in). The important thing is that whatever key strings are entered in the XPage can be found in the user's id in the vault when the doc is being saved... so that encryption can take place.

Comment: There will be a video David :-)

Comment: I've also been working on an OpenNTF Domino API branch for FP8, so we hope to have support for encryption in applications using ODA soon after FP8 release date.